# Binding DataTable to DetailsView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, detailsview

I have a DetailsView control that I want to populate with a data table. I'm doing this in code behind. After checking that the data table is created successfully, the code is:

```
  detailsView.DataSource = dataTable;
    detailsView.DataBind();
```

I run the program and the detailsView doesn't show.Could the problem be that a data table potentially can have multiple rows and a details view only one? If that's the problem is there a way of getting around it? I made sure in creating the data table that it has only one row. I also tried binding only one row in the data table but a data table row isn't accepted as a data source. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you post your DetailsView Design mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add in a `Bound field` or Set the DetailsView `AutoGenerateRows="true"` to display the field in the detailsView. I am sure you forget to do this..

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" >
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FieldName" HeaderText="Field Title" />
            .......................
            .......................
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Setting the autogenerate to true was enough than you very much!

Answer (score -1):

DetailView.DataSource = *DataSetName*; 
DetailView.DataMember = *DataTableName*;

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/319762-Datasource-Datamember-In-GridView.aspx